# How to disable Concurrent execution of long running hangfire job?

Tags: .net, hangfire

**Background:** I am using Hangfire with .net web application to run recurring job, which is scheduled for 3rd Saturday of every month.
But as per the need client can trigger that job manually from hangfire dashboard, this job is long running job some time it might take few hours to complete.

**Issue:**

1. When this job is getting triggered manually sometimes it is automatically getting called
   2 time, not sure why.

   Does any one has idea on this issue?
2. To get rid of this issue I saw many people suggesting DisableConcurrentExecution
   attribute, as this attribute ask for timeout seconds I am doubtful whether it will work
   with long running job.

   Is there any way to avoid calling long running job if one is already started?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get around this in the end, i did the following

These attributes are added to my interfaces

```
[PingUrlToKeepAlive]
[SkipWhenPreviousJobIsRunning]
[DisableConcurrentExecution(10)]
[Queue("{0}")]
```

PingUrl is an attribute created to stop the IIS process from shutting down after 20 minutes on either server, nothing to do with this fix, just thought i would mention it

Queue is the recommended way now according to hangfire.

DisableConcurrentExecution is the attribute i thought i needed only, but you also need the one below.

SkipWhenPreviousJobIsRunning is a new attribute, that looks like this

```
public class SkipWhenPreviousJobIsRunningAttribute: JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IApplyStateFilter
{
    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext context)
    {
        var connection = context.Connection as JobStorageConnection;

        // We can't handle old storages
        if (connection == null) return;

        // We should run this filter only for background jobs based on 
        // recurring ones
        if (!context.Parameters.ContainsKey("RecurringJobId")) return;

        var recurringJobId = context.Parameters["RecurringJobId"] as string;

        // RecurringJobId is malformed. This should not happen, but anyway.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJobId)) return;

        var running = connection.GetValueFromHash($"recurring-job:{recurringJobId}", "Running");
        if ("yes".Equals(running, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Canceled = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (context.NewState is EnqueuedState)
        {
            var recurringJobId = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<string>(context.Connection.GetJobParameter(context.BackgroundJob.Id, "RecurringJobId"));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJobId)) return;

            transaction.SetRangeInHash(
                $"recurring-job:{recurringJobId}",
                new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Running", "yes") });
        }
        else if (context.NewState.IsFinal /* || context.NewState is FailedState*/)
        {
            var recurringJobId = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<string>(context.Connection.GetJobParameter(context.BackgroundJob.Id, "RecurringJobId"));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJobId)) return;

            transaction.SetRangeInHash(
                $"recurring-job:{recurringJobId}",
                new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Running", "no") });
        }
    }

    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
    }
}
```

Basically this checks to see if the job is already running and if so, cancels it.  We now have no problems with jobs running on both servers at the same time.

The above works for recuring jobs, but you can change it easily to work for all jobs.

Comment: Hi Gillardo, I know its been a while but do you still have the link to what explains 'Queue is the recommended way now according to hangfire.'

Thanks

Comment: Was recommended to me by hangfire support.

Comment: I think they meant queues are the recommended way to deal with the IIS idle shut down issue that they were using the `PingUrlToKeepAlive` attribute for.